# MVC3 Extension method <TModel, TValue>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

EDIT:
Thanks to David Ruttka, I was able to figure it out after looking at LabelExtensions.cs from Mvc3's RTM release.

For the field name:
string field = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

For the model, I needed to specify the model I wanted to cast as for the Helper-
where TModel:Foo
then I could get at the model:
BarTypeEnum barType = ((Foo)html.ViewData.Model).BarType;

I've updated the source below to what's working for me.

/EDIT

I'm attempting to create a html helper function similar to LabelFor in Mvc3 to return a string value based on Foo.BarType and the name of Foo's field passed in from the html.

In the function FooLabelFor below, how do I get model and field name passed into the function?

I went looking for the source for System.Web.Mvc.HtmlLabelFor, but was unable to find it in the Mvc3 source code.

```
//model class
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public BarTypeEnum BarType { get; set; }
}

//html helper class
public static class HtmlHelpers {
    public static string FooLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression) where TModel:Foo
    {
        BarTypeEnum barType = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string field = ((Foo)html.ViewData.Model).BarType;
        return GlobalizeText(enumHelper.stringvalue(barType), field);
    }  
}

//html
@model Foo
<div>@Html.FooLabelFor(m => m.Bar)</div>
```

Comment: FWIW `LabelFor` can be found in the `LabelExtensions` class, i.e., `\src\SystemWebMvc\Mvc\Html\LabelExtensions.cs`

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question here.

Comment: @DavidRuttka - Both the source code browser at codeplex: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/77537 and the source code download do not include LabelExtensions.cs. do you know where I can download it?

Comment: I had happened to download and unzip it this morning at 9:41 CST for other reasons. I found the file at the path above. I downloaded the ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM Source Code from https://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases ( https://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781#DownloadId=195410 )

Answer (score 0):

The bar type and field name you will want to pass in as additional arguments to the helper like so:

```
public static string FooLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, BarTypeEnum barType, string fieldName)
 {
  //...
 }
```

Then you will need to add some code in the body of the helper to determine the appropriate text for the label, and let's say you will put that text into a variable called `theText`.  Now all you need is :

```
var theLabel = htmlHelper.Label(id, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(theText));

return MvcHtmlString.Create(theLabel);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Adding (BarTypeEnum barType, string fieldName) is unnecessary, as I should be able to pull the barType from the html parameter, and fieldName from expression.